# Don't show list icon (disc) and have scrollbars

Tags: html, css, list

I want to make a list with `list-style-type: disc;` to list some programs.

But the list-items don't get this "`disc`" and have scrollbars , i don't know why... look here ([Link](http://martin-fischer.tk/)).

It just should be a list with the disc-icon and no scrollbars on the right for every list-tiem.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>flashtool</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `list-style-type` is not working is the absence of `list-style-position: inside`. So your CSS need the following modification:

```
main > ul li .content > ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

in your `common.css` line number 4

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the declaration of the following class.

```
main > ul li
{
 overflow:auto;
}
```

The above code will point the first level `ul` under `main`. That is perfect. But look at the next selector. It will select all the child-selector of `li`. This is wrong in your case. It should point only first level of `li` also. Update the code like below. It will work.

```
main > ul > li
{
 overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.content ul{
     list-style-type:disc;
     list-style-position:inside;
}
```

if you want to remove scrollbar set `overflow:hidden`